# Pointer to table of struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I don't understand some piece of code in **C**, and couldn't find any similar question, so I hope you'll help me.
I have a `struct` table defined like this:

```
struct my_struct {
  struct other_struct some_struct[N];
  char some_char;
  ..
} my_struct[N];
```

In another function:

```
struct my_struct *ms;
```

And then is the part I don't understand:

```
ms = &my_struct[0];
```

How can I interpret this line?

Comment: That is actually the same as `ms = my_struct;`. Perhaps you should read more about the address-of operator `&` (if that's what you wonder about)? If it's not the `&` operator you're wondering about, then perhaps you can edit your question to elaborate on your problem?

Comment: You are using `my_struct` with two different meanings, that does not help with understanding code.

Comment: @Yunnosh The problem was that this piece of code was written by someone else...

Comment: And yes, I suppose I should read more about the & operator, because I have to understand and work with some C code at my studies right now but I don't have actually the strong basics on it :/

Answer (score 2):

`ms` is a pointer to the `struct my_struct`. It contains address of a `struct my_struct` variable. Here we assign to `ms` the already declared `struct my_struct` array's (also name `my_struct`) 0-th element's address.

`&` - address of operator. Which basically returns the address of a variable.

Now you can access `my_struct[0]` via `ms`.

Equivalently

`ms->some_char = 'A'` is same as `my_struct[0].some_char='A'`. To give a small example I can simplify this way.

```
struct a{
  int z;
};

struct a array[10]; // array of 10 `struct a`

struct a* ptr = &array[0]; // ptr contains the address of array[0].
```

Now we can access `array[0]` via pointer `ptr`.

And `ms` is just a `pointer to struct` not `pointer to a table of struct` as you have mentioned in the question heading.

Comment: 1+ (not just) for the last sentence, which probably is the most important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I mentioned in some comment above I don't have strong background in the C language but I'm forced now to work with some already written code at my studies. But you made my problem very simple and now I understand!